# CakePHP 1.3 Media view not downloading ZIP file correctly

Tags: cakephp, download, zip, cakephp-1.3, media

I recently migrated my site from CakePHP 1.1 to 1.3.

I am now using media view to download files, however, I have a major problem.

When I download a zip file through media view, and try to extract it, windows claims the file is empty.  If I try to preview it, it says it is invalid.

- The file size is correct, same size as on server
- I can download the exact same file from the server via FTP, and it is correct
- I can download a pdf file through media view, and IT works correctly (but ZIP files do not)

Here's my controller code:

```
        $this->view = 'Media';
    $downloadparams = array(
          'id' => 'junkstuff'.'.zip',
          'name' => 'junk3',
          'download' => true,
          'extension' => 'zip',  // must be lower case
          'path' => APP . 'tmp/files' . DS   // don't forget terminal 'DS'
     );
   $this->set($downloadparams);
```

Again, if I change to a pdf file, and change 'extension' to 'pdf', it all works correctly.
Debug is set to 0.
My code usage is straight from the 1.3 Cakebook:  http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Views.html

Funny enough, they use zip as an example in the cakebook ....

What might I be doing wrong?

For reference, this thread appears to be the exact same issue, but it has no answers either:
[when opened with winrar, Zip file obtained through Cakephp MediaViews reports Unexpected end of archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208276/when-opened-with-winrar-zip-file-obtained-through-cakephp-mediaviews-reports-un)

Comment: There is a constant for tmp, by the way: `'path' => TMP. 'files' . DS`

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that one.  The file path was working, but I changed it in the interest of simplicity.  Zips still don't work.

Comment: Yeah, that is unrelated :) I never had issues with zip files in 1.3 though. I wonder what could be wrong, especially when other (binary) files like PDF work. Any way to upgrade to 2.x? Then you can drop the whole MediaView and use a clean response approach.

Comment: That was my original plan. Unfortunately, the site owner wants to stop the upgrade at 1.3 in the interest of time.  I keep thinking it's probably something very little that's just being missed.  Would you mind posting your controller code that does work so I can see a working example?  Is there anything OUTSIDE of the controller that might affect it? @mark

Comment: Check the log files. Does it tell you anything? Also check your headers via Firebug. Maybe it sends the wrong headers, thus rendering the file invalid some way.

Comment: @mark - Nothing in the log files.

Here are the headers.  I didn't notice anything strange, but maybe you can.

`Response Headers
Accept-Ranges bytes
Cache-Control private
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition attachment; filename="junk53.zip";
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Length 323232
Content-Type application/octet-stream
Date Thu, 29 Aug 2013 23:17:56 GMT
Expires 0
Keep-Alive timeout=15, max=100
P3P CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Pragma private
Server Apache/2.0.64 (Unix)
Vary Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By PHP/5.2.8`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36495/discussion-between-user2266832-and-mark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when I put the site live on the live server (it was on a server, but my "test" server), this problem fixed itself.  The only thing I can think of it that somewhere there was a reference or a security check that referenced the official site name.  My test site had a different site address.

That's a guess.  I'm really not sure what it fixed itself.  But I didn't change the code, and it started working on the live site.

Answer (score 0):

Your content type might be wrong (which happens when not using the reponse class - which you cannot do in 1.3 of course):

```
Content-Type    application/octet-stream
```

Should better be

```
Content-Type    application/x-compressed
```

Also the content length might be useful.
You can try to add those headers manually using `header()`.

Comment: I tried to manually set the application through the Mime-type option.  However, the browser always used the same type, no matter what I put in there.